# NSMutableArray writeToUrl

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, nsmutablearray

Is it possible to use the:

```
[NSMutableArray writeToURL:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)AuxSomething];
```

In order to send a file (NSMutableArray) XML file to a url, and update the url to contain that file?

for example:
I have an array and I want to upload it to a specific URL and the next time the app launches I want to download that array.

```
NSMutableArray *arrayToWrite = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"One",@"Two",nil];

[arrayToWrite writeToURL:

[NSURL urlWithString:@"mywebsite.atwebpages.com/myArray.plist"] atomically:YES];
```

And at runtime:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayToRead = 

[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL           urlWithString:@"mywebsite.atwebpages.com/myArray.plist"]];
```

Meaning, I want to write an NSMutableArray to a URL, which is on a web hosting service (e.g. batcave.net, the URL receives the information and updates server sided files accordingly.
A highscore like setup, user sends his scores, the server updates it's files, other users download the highscores at runtime.

Comment: You'll have to be a lot more clear in your question - what do you mean "write into a URL"? Do you want to append the contents of the array to a URL based at your host? Or do you want to upload the data in the array to a certain place on your website?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a highscore like system, iPhone side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023289/creating-a-highscore-like-system-iphone-side)

Answer (score 1):

As for part one of your question,
I'll assume you want to use the contents of a NSMutableArray to form some sort of a URL request (like [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP))) that you will send to your web service and expect back some information...

There is no prebuilt way of sending the contents of a NSMutableArray to an URL but there are simple ways of doing this yourself. For example, you can loop through the data of your array and make use of [NSURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to create a URL request that complies with the interface of your web service. Once you've constructed your request you can send it by passing it a [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object.

Consider this very simple and incomplete example of what the client-side code might look like using an Obj-C array to provide data...

```
NSMutableData *dataReceived; // Assume exists and is initialized
NSURLConnection *myConnection;

- (void)startRequest{
    NSLog(@"Start");

    NSString *baseURLAddress = @"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/";

    // This is the array we'll use to help make the URL request
    NSArray *names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Jonny_Appleseed",nil];
    NSString *completeURLAsString = [baseURLAddress stringByAppendingString: [names objectAtIndex:0]];

    //NSURLRequest needs a NSURL Object
    NSURL *completeURL = [NSURL URLWithString: completeURLAsString];

    NSURLRequest *myURLRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: completeURL];

    // self is the delegate, this means that this object will hanlde
    // call-backs as the data transmission from the web server progresses
    myConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:myURLRequest delegate: self startImmediately:YES];
}

// This is called automatically when there is new data from the web server,
// we collect the server response and save it
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"Got some");
    [dataReceived appendData: data];
}

// This is called automatically when transmission of data is complete
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // You now have whatever the server sent...
}
```

To tackle part 2 of your question, the receiver of a web request will likely require some scripting or infrastructure to make a useful response.

Answer (score 1):

Here, Answer in this question: 
 
[Creating a highscore like system, iPhone side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023289/nsmutablearray-writetourl)

I couldn't edit my post because I posted from my iPhone as an anonymous user, sorry.